# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker does not reapper after continuous clicks

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker that shows up when the field is clicked and hides if clicked again. However, if clicked for the third time, the calendar does not appear. If you unfocus the field and then click it again - it appears.

I'm clueless.

HTML :

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <input id="setdate-date" class="form-control" type="text" name="Date" value="@Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <span class="input-group-addon datepickerbutton start-date-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
        $(function () {

            var today = new Date();

            var endDate = new Date(@Model.MaxDate.Year, @(Model.MaxDate.Month - 1), @Model.MaxDate.Day, @Model.MaxDate.Hour, @Model.MaxDate.Minute, 0, 0);

            $('#setdate-date').datetimepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
                startDate: today,
                endDate: endDate,
                autoclose: true
            });

            $('#setdate-date').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());

            $('#form-setdate .datepickerbutton').click(function () {
                $('#setdate-date').datetimepicker('show');             
            });
        })
        </script>
```

Any ideas ? The same occurs on all of my datetimepickers.

Regards

edit: I tried applying .blur() on $('#setdate-date') so it unfocuses after a click but to no avail :/

Comment: Aren't, you initiating datetimepicker too many times? Please check the documentation.

Comment: Am I ? If I knew I wouldn't ask!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use datepicker:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you have different scenarios: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Friend, my setup works just as intended, except the reopening part. I wouldn't have asked had I not not read the documentation. It works just fine, I just can't seem to open it after closing it without unfocusing.

Comment: Cool. I will not think too much about it but have you checked how it will behave if you initialize it only once? And also I see in the documentation that the datetimepicker1 id is on the div not in the input field. I don't know if it matters.